# Heroku removes bundler when deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I'm in trouble with deployment of my ruby-on-rails app on heroku.

Deploy failed with following logs.

> Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e staging -p 6882`
>
> bash: bundle: command not found

And I noticed when deploy, bundler(1.3.2) is removed and bundler(1.5.2) is used even if I specify bundler version as '1.3.2'.

When deploy, `Using bundler(1.5.2)` is shown but there is no bundler in `heroku run 'gem list'`.

This is happen after I pushed the commit that includes some gem's updates.

After that deploy, all deploys are failed even if I deloy the commit that worked well before.

Comment: I believe Heroku uses something like rvm or rbenv in order to install ruby and the gemsets. If this is the case, I believe they put the `bundler` gem in the global gemset. They may have tools on their system that require a certain version of bundler, or that is the version they have done their testing on.

Comment: Can you do `heroku run bash` and at the bash prompt do a `gem install bundler`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ruby definition in your gemfile like so?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.15'

.....
```

if you do, heroku will try to load bundler 1.5.2
try to update bundler like so

```
gem update bundler
```

then commit & push to heroku

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone.

I fixed up this problem.

I tried all solutions in this post but couldn't get fixed, so I asked the heroku's support with detail information.

It is because I'm using the custom buildpack that not support Bundler 1.5.2.

So, I configure an app to use [the Official Ruby Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby)

> heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby